# Excluding ch.qos.logback overflows

Tags: logging, gradle, build.gradle, slf4j

I'm using:

```
compile (libs.spring_boot_starter_logging)
testCompile 'org.apache.qpid:qpid-broker:0.28'
```

Both of them have a SLF4J binding, so I have error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/maciej.glowala.ext/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/ccedfbacef4a6515d2983e3f89ed753d5d4fb665/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/maciej.glowala.ext/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/6b4973e0320e220ec6534478d60233fd1cc51c9b/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

I can exclude version 1.6.4 from qpid-broker but it make error because broker cannot find some method which is included in newer version. When I want to exclude version 1.1.11

```
compile (libs.spring_boot_starter_logging){
            exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
        }
```

I've got an overflow error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:64)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
    .
    .
    .
```

What is more, I shouldn't exclude from `compile` when `SLF4J` binding is included in `testCompile` so I wanted to exclude for tests only using

```
configurations {
    testCompile.exclude group:'ch.qos.logback'
}
```

But anyway I have still the same overflow error. Anyone can help me how to set build.gradle to use newer version for tests?

Answer (score 1):

If someone will need it in the future, solved it by additional exclude:

```
testCompile.exclude group:'org.slf4j', module:'log4j-over-slf4j'
```